# Multivariate Classification: Suppose the $p$-dimensional observation $x_o$ either belongs to population $\Pi_1$ or $\Pi_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose the $p$-dimensional observation $x_o$ either belongs to population $\Pi_1$ or $\Pi_2$ where $\Pi_i\sim N_p (\mu_i,\Sigma)$ and $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\Sigma$ are known. Suppose we use the following classification rule: classify $x_0$ into $\Pi_1$ by

$$(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T \Sigma^{-1} x_0 - \frac{1}{2}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 + \mu_2) > -1.46$$

Calculate the probability of misclassification $e_1$. Suppose $\Delta = 1,$ obtain $e_1$.

Here $\Delta^2 = (\mu_1 -\mu_2)^T \Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$

---

I start this out knowing

$$e_1 = \Phi \left( \frac{k-\delta^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1}{\sqrt{\delta^T\Sigma^{-1}\delta}} \right)$$

Because $\Delta = 1$, the denominator should equal $1$ as well since it's the square root of the Mahalanobis distance.

But now I have;

$$e_1 = \Phi(k-\delta^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_1)$$

I then have,

$$k = \frac{1}{2}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 + \mu_2) + 1.46$$

But beyond this I'm completely stuck. The nice properties when $e_1 = e_2$ don't apply here so I'm not sure how to solve such a problem.

Edit:

I found something else regarding cost of misclassification. Is the following useful?:

$$K_p = K_0 + d$$ where $d=\log(c_2q_2/c_1q_1)$

Then

$$e_1 = \Phi(-\frac{1}{2}\Delta + d\Delta^{-1})$$

The book define $c_1$ as the cost of misclassifying an observation from popuation 1 and $q_1 as the prior probability that an observation comes from population 1. How do I use this?

Thank you in advance!

Edit 2: 
Wait, is the following correct?

$$\log\left(\frac{c_2 q_2}{c_1 q_1}\right) = 1.46$$

If so I can write

$$e_1 = \Phi\left(-\frac{1}{2} - 1.46\right)$$

Comment: If you have a probability that the observation was from $\Pi_i$ for $i=1,2,$ then you could speak of the probability that it's correctly or incorrectly classified. But if I understand the problem, with what you've got, you can find a conditional probability of misclassification given that it's from $\Pi_1$ or form $\Pi_2,$ but not a marginal probability.

Comment: Oh I probably should have defined $e_1$ as well then. $e_1$ is defined as the probability of misclassifying from $\Pi_1$ to $\Pi_2$. Does that change anything?

Comment: I take it you mean $e_1$ is the _conditional_ probability that it's classified as belonging to $\Pi_2$ _given_ that it's in $\Pi_1.$ But do you also have marginal (i.e. "unconditional" or "prior") probabilities of $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: I don't believe so. I included everything on the problem before the dividing line. That's why I was hoping to have those values so I can calculate the log and get d.

Comment: Oh and additionally yes that is what I mean for $e_1$. The book just calls it the probability of misclassifying from $\Pi_1$ to $\Pi_2$ so yes it seems to be the conditional probability.

Comment: Do you not believe that this -1.46 = $log(\frac{c_2q_2}{c_1 q_1})$ is a valid interpretation? After all, we seem to be subtracting K from $a^T x_0$ so perhaps in this case d = -1.46

Comment: ok, So you're looking for a conditional probability given that the population from which the observation was taken was $\Pi_1.$ The problem definitely admits an answer in that case. BTW, you could work on your MathJax technique a bit. Contrast -1.46=$log(\frac{c_2 q_2}{c_1 q_1})$ with $-1.46 = \log\left( \frac{ c_2 q_1}{c_1 q_1} \right). \qquad$

Comment: Did you mean $(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_2)$ rather than $(\mu_1 - \mu_2)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 + \mu_2) \text { ?} \qquad$